# awk - gensub function

Tags: awk

I need to insert contents of variable to parameter function `gensub` in `awk`, specifically instead of regular expression's parameter.

I have:

```
gawk '
 BEGIN {
   a = "abc15d56ef";
   b = gensub(/.*([0-9][0-9])d([0-9][0-9]).*/, "\\2 \\1", "g", a);
   print b;
 }'
```

#### output

```
output:56 15
```

I need it to be in this form, but it doesn't work:

```
gawk '
 BEGIN {
   a = "abc15d56ef";
   c="/.*([0-9][0-9])d([0-9][0-9]).*/";
   b = gensub(c, "\\2 \\1", "g", a);
   print b;
 }'
```

#### output

```
output:56 15
```

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
gawk '
 BEGIN {
   a = "abc15d56ef"
   c=".*([0-9][0-9])d([0-9][0-9]).*"
   b = gensub(c, "\\2 \\1", "1", a)
   print b
 }'
56 15
```

--
edit: Added number in the third field after comment by @luckman212

Comment: In the above form, I get a warning about the 3rd argument to `gensub()` being blank. It should be either "1" (1st match) or "g" (all): `gensub(c, "\\2 \\1", "g", a)`

Comment: @luckman212. What version of gawk are you using, I get no such warning in gawk 4.02. I agree that the man page specifies a number..

Comment: v5.0.0 from Homebrew.